# counting the occurrences in a list of lists python

Tags: python, list, find-occurrences

I have a list of lists in python:

```
x=[['1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '1', '0', '0'],  
['1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0'], 
['0', '0', '1', '2', '1', '0', '2', '1', '1']]
```

I want to know how count the occurrences in the list of lists

My output should be like (without using numpy and Counter):

```
{'1': 3, '2': 4, '0': 2}
{'1': 5, '0': 4}
{'0': 3, '1': 4, '2': 2}
```

Now, I have the solution which works for only one list, but doesn't work for list of lists.

```
newlist=[]
for el in x:
    n=el[0]
    newlist.append(n)
print(newlist)
 
list2=dict((i, newlist.count(i)) for i in newlist)
print(list2)
```

I did't find an answer on another thread. Is anyone able to help? :)

Comment: `dict((i, newlist.count(i)) for i in newlist)` is an inefficient algorithm fo counting. See the two top-rated answers in the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

```
count_dict = []
for el in x:
    count = {}
    for i in el: count[i] = count.get(i, 0) + 1
    count_dict.append(count)
```

`count_dict` will look like this:

```
[
  {'1': 3, '2': 4, '0': 2},
  {'1': 5, '0': 4},
  {'0': 3, '1': 4, '2': 2}
]
```

Comment: This is an unnecessarily inefficient algorithm. Don't use it. It is O(N**2) and you can trivially do it in O(N)

Comment: I closed the question, this is a well-known duplicate. See the duplicate target for an efficient algorithm, basically, `count = {}` then just `for x in sublist: count[x] = count.get(x, 0) + 1` Which is what `collections.Counter` implements, only in optimized C-level code

Comment: Yeah. this only works for 1D lists. He's asking for 2D lists. Hence the extra for loop.

Comment: Obviously it is meant to count the results *in each sublist*. It is meant to replace `{i:el.count(i) for i in el}` not the whole thing. This is a well-known anti-pattern

Comment: Yeah but you're also using a for loop. So isn't this O(N**2) as well?

Comment: No. `{i:el.count(i) for i in el}` is quadratic time on the size of the sublist. The algorithm I used above is linear time on the size of the sublist. Note, `el.count(i)` is linear time. Again, **this is a well-known antipattern with a well-known alternative**.

Answer (score 0):

You are just taking the first 'sublist' into account, loop once more:

```
x = [
    ['1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '1', '0', '0'],
    ['1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0'],
    ['0', '0', '1', '2', '1', '0', '2', '1', '1']
]

for lst in x:
    newlist = []
    for sublst in lst:
        newlist.append(sublst)

    list2 = dict((i, newlist.count(i)) for i in newlist)
    print(list2)
```

Out:

```
{'1': 3, '2': 4, '0': 2}
{'1': 5, '0': 4}
{'0': 3, '1': 4, '2': 2}
```

Comment: Unnecessarily inefficient algorithm.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: All that 'inefficiency' blaming won't make it better and OP didn't ask about that, in the first place. The first dup has no accepted answer, both questions got a lot of answers, I don't get which of those answers you are referring to. It would be more understandable if you at least comment on the question ...

Comment: What? What are you talking about "inefficiency blaming". Look I'm pointing out that this is a classic anti-pattern, i.e. `result = {x:mylist.count(x) for x in mylist}` is quadratic time. You can use a simple `result = {}` then `for x in mylist: result[x] = result.get(x,0) + 1` for a linear time solution. A well-known solution. In the linked duplicate, the top two rated answers have this more efficient algorithm (`collections.Counter` does this for `Counter(mylist)`, just that it is implemented in optimized C-level code).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method

```
x=[['1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '1', '0', '0'],  
  ['1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0'], 
  ['0', '0', '1', '2', '1', '0', '2', '1', '1']]

for i in x:
    data={}
    for j in i:
        if j not in data:
            data[j]=i.count(j)
    print(data)
```

output:

[image]

or :

```
for i in x:
    data={}
    for j in i:
        data[j]=i.count(j)
    print(data)
```

output :

[image]

Comment: This algorithm is unnecessarily inefficient.

Comment: I think there are other ways to improve the algorithm and this is a simple example

Comment: I'm merely pointing this out because this algorithm is a well-known anti-pattern, with a well-known alternative. See the linked duplicate above.

Comment: If you look at the image above, `if j  not in  data`
Prevents unintentional use of the `count` method

Comment: Naturally, calculating duplicate values ​​in the list is heavier than checking the availability of a value

Comment: Ah, nevermind, I misread it.